# Searching though a text file using C#

Tags: c#

Hi i am having some trouble with a piece of code of mine and ive been trying to google the answers but for some wierd reason i cant get this to work properly.

The current code is working, but it does not stop the search when it found the "offline" in the txt file making it rather pointless as the programs pings a number of ip addresses and when it finds a offline unit has to mark the store name in red to notify the technician monitoring the stores. what happens is it scans the file created and changes the color from red to green for each line. instead of searching for the word offline and once found stop the search and change the color.

so my question is how do i make this stop once it found the first line containing offline?

the code i have so far is this please oif you can see my mistake please let me know.

```
var filename = "C:\\Scales\\scalecheck.txt";
var searchTarget = "offline";
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    if (line.Contains(searchTarget))
    {
        var test = storeNumber;
        var labels = Controls.Find("storename" + test, true);
        if (labels.Length > 0)
        {
            var label = (Label)labels[0];
            label.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var test1 = storeNumber;
        var labels = Controls.Find("storename" + test1, true);
        if (labels.Length > 0)
        {
            var label = (Label)labels[0];
            label.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show an excerpt of the text file that reproduces the problem. It looks like you just need a `break`.

Comment: to explain further my text file contains Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
offline
Online
Online

Comment: to explain further my text file contains Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
Online
offline
Online
Online with 1 offline but becuase the last entry is online it shows green  and not the red to indicate a offline unit was found

Comment: thanks missed the break, worked 100%